# Character recognition from images model remains at 0% accuracy and nan loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to build a neural network to identify and generate strings corresponding to characters found in the image (a-z,A-Z,0-9).

I am using the [Char74kFnt dataset](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/)

My train/test images/labels are all numpy arrays.  **Each of the 62 classes of characters has 1016 images. So the total number of images is 62992. I chose 75% of the dataset for training data.**  Originally, the train/test labels were the characters themselves, but that gave me value errors (eg : Error converting string to float 'b') so I mapped int(ord(x)) onto the labels.  My train/test data is formatted as follows in a numpy array:

- train & test_images.shape (x,128,128)  eg: 128x128 image size
- Values:

train & test_images(0:1016,128,128) is corresponds to all '0'

.

.

.

train & test_images(61976:,128,128) is corresponds to all 'z'

- values are normalized for all images ( x / 255)
- And these images match the dimensions/correspond to the correct train & test label index.

**My issue is that when I train this model I stay at 0% accuracy and nan loss (see code)**

```
from Char74k import Char74kFntDataSet
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

a=Char74kFntDataSet()


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(128, 128)),
    keras.layers.Dense(120, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(62, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(a.train_images, a.train_labels, epochs=2)
```

**Is it possible that my dataset is not large enough?** Or is there some simple error (non-ideal parameter, possible incorrect/non-ideal data input, etc) or another particular model I should use instead of this one?

The following command line snippet shows the 0% accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/2
47244/47244 [==============================] - 43s 908us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
47244/47244 [==============================] - 28s 587us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
15748/15748 [==============================] - 12s 749us/step
Test accuracy: 0.0
```

Comment: Your model implementation might be correct, but the *model* itself (a simple NN with just 1 hidden layer) is probably insufficient. I suggest trying a CNN model...